# how can I pass data between view Model class and foreground service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, viewmodel, foreground-service

I have an app that connect with Bluetooth to a BLE device with MVVM architect and LiveData

now I want to use foreground service till I can stay connect with device and get data from device even app is closed like Mi band android app

or my app can connect with device whenever foreground service is open and Bluetooth is enable even app is closed

how can I do that?
how can i pass data between view Model class and foreground service without using activity

if you have best practice for my problem please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Read nice [github repository](https://github.com/uberchilly/BoundServiceMVVM) with great attached articles in it.